# Java File/Path issue Programm in Eclipse works, but not as exported jar (Unknown Source)

Tags: java, eclipse, image, file, jar

I learned something about Java in school and as I had lots of fun, I tried to make my own small programs. At the moment, I'm trying to do a program, that can organize  collections. This is the first time, that I want touse pictures and I'm still having some problems, so I hope your could help me. Thank you!

I'm using some [JGUI Toolbox](http://ovtg-alt.ovtg.de/3_arbeit/informatik/JGUIWeb/JGUIStart.html), we got froom school, which has an special class for pictures:

```
    //%$JGUIToolbox$%//ID fuer Toolboxdateien

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 * <h1>Bildklasse zur Darstellung einer Bilddatei</h1>.<br/>
 * 
 * @author Hans Witt, Claus Behl
 * 
 * @version Version 1 (4.12.08)<br/>
 *          Version 5.0: (4.9.2010) Entfernen fuer Graphikkomponente eingefuehrt<br/>
 * 
 */
public class Bild implements IComponente {
    private CBild obj;
    private BufferedImage bild;
    protected int breite = 0;
    protected int hoehe = 0;

    protected int xPos = 0;
    protected int yPos = 0;
    protected boolean sichtbar = true;
    protected boolean zoomen = false;

    /**
     * 
     * @param filename
     */
    public Bild(String filename) {
        this(Zeichnung.gibZeichenflaeche(), filename);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param datei
     */
    public Bild(BilddateiAbstrakt datei) {
        this(Zeichnung.gibZeichenflaeche(), datei);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param neueBreite
     * @param neueHoehe
     * @param filename
     */
    public Bild(int neueBreite, int neueHoehe, String filename) {
        this(Zeichnung.gibZeichenflaeche(), 0, 0, neueBreite, neueHoehe,
                filename);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param neueBreite
     * @param neueHoehe
     * @param datei
     */
    public Bild(int neueBreite, int neueHoehe, BilddateiAbstrakt datei) {
        this(Zeichnung.gibZeichenflaeche(), 0, 0, neueBreite, neueHoehe, datei);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param neuesX
     * @param neuesY
     * @param neueBreite
     * @param neueHoehe
     * @param filename
     */
    public Bild(int neuesX, int neuesY, int neueBreite, int neueHoehe,
            String filename) {
        this(Zeichnung.gibZeichenflaeche(), neuesX, neuesY, neueBreite,
                neueHoehe, filename);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param neuesX
     * @param neuesY
     * @param neueBreite
     * @param neueHoehe
     * @param datei
     */
    public Bild(int neuesX, int neuesY, int neueBreite, int neueHoehe,
            BilddateiAbstrakt datei) {
        this(Zeichnung.gibZeichenflaeche(), neuesX, neuesY, neueBreite,
                neueHoehe, datei);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param behaelter
     * @param filename
     */
    public Bild(IContainer behaelter, String filename) {
        this(behaelter, 0, 0, 100, 100, filename);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param behaelter
     * @param datei
     */
    public Bild(IContainer behaelter, BilddateiAbstrakt datei) {
        this(behaelter, 0, 0, 100, 100, datei);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param behaelter
     * @param neuesX
     * @param neuesY
     * @param neueBreite
     * @param neueHoehe
     * @param filename
     */
    public Bild(IContainer behaelter, int neuesX, int neuesY, int neueBreite,
            int neueHoehe, String filename) {
        bild = setzeBilddatei(filename);
        obj = new CBild(bild);
        behaelter.add(obj, 0);
        breite = neueBreite;
        hoehe = neueHoehe;

        if (bild != null) {
            setzeDimensionen(neuesX, neuesY, bild.getWidth(), bild.getHeight());
        } else {
            setzeDimensionen(neuesX, neuesY, neueBreite, neueHoehe);
        }

        setzeDimensionen(neuesX, neuesY, neueBreite, neueHoehe);

        behaelter.validate();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param behaelter
     * @param neuesX
     * @param neuesY
     * @param neueBreite
     * @param neueHoehe
     * @param datei
     */
    public Bild(IContainer behaelter, int neuesX, int neuesY, int neueBreite,
            int neueHoehe, BilddateiAbstrakt datei) {
        bild = datei.leseBild();
        obj = new CBild(bild);
        behaelter.add(obj, 0);
        breite = neueBreite;
        hoehe = neueHoehe;

        if (bild != null) {
            setzeDimensionen(neuesX, neuesY, bild.getWidth(), bild.getHeight());
        } else {
            setzeDimensionen(neuesX, neuesY, neueBreite, neueHoehe);
        }

        setzeDimensionen(neuesX, neuesY, neueBreite, neueHoehe);

        behaelter.validate();
    }

    public int leseBildBreite() {
        if (bild == null)
            return 0;
        return bild.getWidth();
    }

    public int leseBildHoehe() {
        if (bild == null)
            return 0;
        return bild.getHeight();
    }

    /**
     * Das Interface IComponente fordert eine Methode die eine BasisComponente
     * zurueckliefert. Sie wird benoetigt, um ein Objekt zu einem anderen
     * Behaelter hinzuzufuegen
     */
    @Override
    public BasisComponente getBasisComponente() {
        return obj;
    }

    static int lesen = 0;

    /*
     * Waehle das Bild aus!
     */

private BufferedImage setzeBilddatei(String filename) {   //This is the method to set a new picture, I think it tries to differentiate between pictures in the jar file and pictures on the harddrive, but it seems to be "broken"
        BufferedImage bBild;
        try {

            // Aus jar-Datei lesen
            //InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            InputStream stream = Bild.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + filename);
            if (stream != null) {
                // lesen aus jar
                bBild = ImageIO.read(stream);
            } else if (!Zeichnung.applet) {
                bBild = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
            } else {
                lesen++;
                int height = -1;
                int width = -1;

                Image bild = Zeichnung.pApplet.getImage(
                        Zeichnung.pApplet.getDocumentBase(), filename);
                height = bild.getHeight(null);
                width = bild.getWidth(null);
                if ((height < 0) || (width < 0)) {
                    bBild = new BufferedImage(100, 100,
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

                    Graphics2D g2 = bBild.createGraphics();
                    g2.drawString("!" + lesen, 20, 50);

                } else {
                    bBild = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
                    Graphics2D g2 = bBild.createGraphics();
                    g2.drawImage(bild, 0, 0, null);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Das Bild ist nicht vorhanden");
            bBild = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

            Graphics2D g2 = bBild.createGraphics();
            g2.drawString("Kein Bild !", 20, 50);
        }

        return bBild;
    }

    /*
     * Bild wird in das Fenster eingepasst
     */
    public void einpassen() {
        zoomen = true;

        double faktor = 1;

        if (bild != null) {
            faktor = (breite * 1.0) / (bild.getWidth() * 1.0);

            double faktor2 = (hoehe * 1.0) / (bild.getHeight() * 1.0);

            if (faktor2 < faktor) {
                faktor = faktor2;
            }
        } else {
            faktor = 1;
        }

        obj.setzeAnpassungsfaktor(faktor);
    }

    /*
     * Keine Anpassung des Bilds
     */
    public void normal() {
        zoomen = false;
        obj.setzeAnpassungsfaktor(1);
    }

    /**
     * zeigt Bild vollstaendig an
     */
    public void expandieren() {
        setzeDimensionen(xPos, yPos, bild.getWidth(), bild.getHeight());
    }

    /*
     * @param String filename Der Name der gewuenschten BilddateiAbstrakt
     */
    public void wechsleBild(String filename) {
        bild = setzeBilddatei(filename);

        if (bild != null) {
            if (zoomen) {
                setzeDimensionen(xPos, yPos, breite, hoehe);
            } else {
                setzeDimensionen(xPos, yPos, bild.getWidth(), bild.getHeight());
            }
        }

        obj.wechsleBild(bild);
    }

    /*
     * @param String filename Der Name der gewuenschten BilddateiAbstrakt
     */
    public void wechsleBild(BilddateiAbstrakt datei) {
        bild = datei.leseBild();

        if (bild != null) {
            if (zoomen) {
                setzeDimensionen(xPos, yPos, breite, hoehe);
            } else {
                setzeDimensionen(xPos, yPos, bild.getWidth(), bild.getHeight());
            }
        }

        obj.wechsleBild(bild);
    }

    public void sichtbarMachen() {
        sichtbar = true;
        obj.sichtbarMachen();
    }

    /**
     * Mache unsichtbar. Wenn es bereits unsichtbar ist, tue nichts.
     */
    public void unsichtbarMachen() {
        sichtbar = false;
        obj.unsichtbarMachen();
    }

    /**
     * Bewege horizontal um 'entfernung' Bildschirmpunkte.
     */
    public void nachRechtsBewegen() {
        horizontalBewegen(20);
    }

    /**
     * Bewege einige Bildschirmpunkte nach links.
     */
    public void nachLinksBewegen() {
        horizontalBewegen(-20);
    }

    /**
     * Bewege einige Bildschirmpunkte nach oben.
     */
    public void nachObenBewegen() {
        vertikalBewegen(-20);
    }

    /**
     * Bewege einige Bildschirmpunkte nach unten.
     */
    public void nachUntenBewegen() {
        vertikalBewegen(20);
    }

    /**
     * Bewege vertikal um 'entfernung' Bildschirmpunkte.
     */
    public void langsamVertikalBewegen(int entfernung) {
        int delta;

        if (entfernung < 0) {
            delta = -1;
            entfernung = -entfernung;
        } else {
            delta = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < entfernung; i++) {
            vertikalBewegen(delta);
            StaticTools.warte(10);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bewege vertikal um 'entfernung' Bildschirmpunkte.
     */
    public void langsamHorizontalBewegen(int entfernung) {
        int delta;

        if (entfernung < 0) {
            delta = -1;
            entfernung = -entfernung;
        } else {
            delta = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < entfernung; i++) {
            horizontalBewegen(delta);
            StaticTools.warte(10);
        }
    }

    public void setzeGroesse(int neueBreite, int neueHoehe) {
        breite = neueBreite;
        hoehe = neueHoehe;

        if (zoomen) {
            einpassen();
        }

        obj.setzeGroesse(breite, hoehe);
    }

    /**
     * neue Position
     * 
     * @param neuesX
     * @param neuesY
     */
    public void setzePosition(int neuesX, int neuesY) {
        xPos = neuesX;
        yPos = neuesY;
        obj.setzePosition(xPos, yPos);
    }

    // Methode noetig zum Hinzufuegen mit Anpassung beim Behaelter
    // Die Enden werden relativ zur aktuellen position verschoben
    public void verschieben(int dx, int dy) {
        setzePosition(xPos + dx, yPos + dy);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param neuesX
     * @param neuesY
     * @param neueBreite
     * @param neueHoehe
     */
    public void setzeDimensionen(int neuesX, int neuesY, int neueBreite,
            int neueHoehe) {
        xPos = neuesX;
        yPos = neuesY;
        breite = neueBreite;
        hoehe = neueHoehe;

        if (zoomen) {
            einpassen();
        }

        obj.setzeDimensionen(xPos, yPos, breite, hoehe);
    }

    /**
     * Bewege horizontal um 'entfernung' Bildschirmpunkte.
     */
    public void horizontalBewegen(int entfernung) {
        xPos += entfernung;
        obj.setzePosition(xPos, yPos);
    }

    /**
     * Bewege vertikal um 'entfernung' Bildschirmpunkte.
     */
    public void vertikalBewegen(int entfernung) {
        yPos += entfernung;
        obj.setzePosition(xPos, yPos);
    }

    /**
     * Entfernen des Graphikobjekts
     */
    public void entfernen() {
        if (obj != null) {
            obj.ausContainerEntfernen();
            obj = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destruktor
     */
    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        if (!Zeichnung.verweistesGUIElementEntfernen)
            return;
        if (obj != null)
            entfernen();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CBild extends BasisComponente {
    private BufferedImage bild;
    private Image bildM;
    private double anpassung = 1; // Faktor zum Einpassen an das

    // Fenstert

    /**
     * Konstruktor ohne Beschriftung
     */
    public CBild(BufferedImage bild) {
        this.bild = bild;
        this.bildM = bild;
    }

    public void wechsleBild(BufferedImage bild) {
        this.bild = bild;
        setzeZoomfaktor(zoomFaktor);
    }

    /**
     * Die Darstellung der Komponente wird hier programmiert.
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponentSpezial(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Graphik-Abmessungen
        breite = getSize().width;
        hoehe = getSize().height;

        g2.drawImage(bildM, 0, 0, null);
    }

    /*
     * Anpassung fuer Einfuegen in das Fenster
     */
    public void setzeAnpassungsfaktor(double zf) {
        anpassung = zf;
        setzeZoomfaktor(zoomFaktor);
    }

    @Override
    public double setzeZoomfaktor(double zf) {
        zoomFaktor = zf;
        bzf = ((IContainer) this.getParent()).getBehaelterZoom();
        bildM = bild.getScaledInstance((int) (bild.getWidth() * zoomFaktor
                * bzf * anpassung),
                (int) (bild.getHeight() * zoomFaktor * bzf * anpassung),
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        zoomen();

        if (sichtbar) {
            ((IContainer) this.getParent()).setzeKomponentenKoordinaten(this,
                    xPos, yPos, breite, hoehe);
        } else {
            ((IContainer) this.getParent()).setzeKomponentenKoordinaten(this,
                    xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
        }

        return zoomFaktor;
    }
}
```

In this VIEW_Start class is everything, that the user should see when starting the program. I also want to show a picture, that is saved in C:/Users/ME/Pictures/fl/stopper-1087835_1280.png When opening the program in eclipse everything works just fine, but as soon as I try to open the exported jar (Package required libraries in jar). CMD tells me about this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
        at Bild.setzeBilddatei(Bild.java:208)
        at Bild.<init>(Bild.java:129)
        at Bild.<init>(Bild.java:83)
        at VIEW_Start.erzeugen(VIEW_Start.java:50)
        at VIEW_Start.<init>(VIEW_Start.java:39)
        at CONTROLLER.<init>(CONTROLLER.java:16)
        at START.main(START.java:6)
```

This is the code of the Class VIEW_Start:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
//import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class VIEW_Start {
    //Layout und Grafik
    static int width=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
    protected Rechteck hintergrund_s;
    protected Taste suchen, plus, bearbeiten;   //Knöpfe
    protected Ausgabe anzeige1, anzeige2, manage;

    protected Bild vorschau;

        //Zeichen
        protected char b = '\u270E';    //Stift
        protected char n = '\u002B';    //Plus
    //Verknüpfung MVC
    protected CONTROLLER control;
    protected MODEL model;

    public VIEW_Start(CONTROLLER con, MODEL mod) {
        //Verknüpfung
        control = con;

        model = mod;


        //Layout und Grafik


            Zeichnung.setzeScrollbar(false);

            //Zeichnung.single.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

            Zeichnung.single.setResizable(false);           

            this.erzeugen();

    }

    public void erzeugen() {

        int width_new = width/10; //to adapt the program to different resolutions

            hintergrund_s = new Rechteck(width_new*0,width_new*0,width_new*120,width_new*80);
            hintergrund_s.setzeFarbe("hintergrund");  //flat Backgroundcolor

            vorschau = new Bild(width_new*35,width_new*6,width_new*50,width_new*50,"C:/Users/ME/Pictures/fl/stopper-1087835_1280.png");   //The picture I want to show from the path

            vorschau.einpassen();


            //Headline
                manage = new Ausgabe("Kronkorken-Manager",width_new*40,width_new*25,width_new*40,width_new*6);
                manage.setzeSchriftgroesse(width_new*3);


            //Show Date and Time
                SimpleDateFormat date1 =new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                String datef1 = date1.format(new Date());

                SimpleDateFormat date2 =new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                String datef2 = date2.format(new Date());

                anzeige1 = new Ausgabe (datef1, width_new*43, width_new*30, width_new*20, width_new*10);
                anzeige1.setzeSchriftgroesse(width_new*2);
                anzeige2 = new Ausgabe (datef2, width_new*55, width_new*30, width_new*20, width_new*10);
                anzeige2.setzeSchriftgroesse(width_new*2);


            //Edit-Button
                bearbeiten = new Taste(""+b+"",width_new*10,width_new*65,width_new*10,width_new*10);
                bearbeiten.setzeSchriftgroesse(width_new*4);
                bearbeiten.setzeHintergrundfarbe("akzent");
                bearbeiten.setzeSchriftfarbe("weiss");
                bearbeiten.setzeLink(control);
                bearbeiten.setzeID(0);

            //Search-Button
                suchen = new Taste("SUCHEN",width_new*40,width_new*65,width_new*40,width_new*10);
                suchen.setzeSchriftgroesse(width_new*3);
                suchen.setzeHintergrundfarbe("akzent");
                suchen.setzeSchriftfarbe("weiss");
                suchen.setzeLink(control);
                suchen.setzeID(1);

            //Add-Button
                plus = new Taste(""+n+"",width_new*100,width_new*65,width_new*10,width_new*10);
                plus.setzeSchriftgroesse(width_new*4);
                plus.setzeHintergrundfarbe("akzent");
                plus.setzeSchriftfarbe("weiss");
                plus.setzeLink(control);
                plus.setzeID(2);
    }

    public void loeschen() { //deletes all objects
        hintergrund_s.entfernen();
        manage.entfernen();
        anzeige1.entfernen();
        anzeige2.entfernen();
        bearbeiten.entfernen();
        suchen.entfernen();
        plus.entfernen();

    }

}
```

I hope everything is clear for you as part of my code is in german. If you have any questions or need more code, please tell me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're totally right. The problem is, that the Toolbox I wanted to use (as I thought it  would be easier, which turned out to be wrong) is in german and therefore I had to use german sometimes.  I still tried to tanslate the important parts or added annotations in english.

I tried to debug the code in Eclipse. In eclispe the differentiation between files integrated in the project and external files (e.g. C://x//x//) works just fine. Is there any option, to debug the .jar file simmiliar to the code in eclipse?

Comment: First, you need to understand what `getResource` actually does.  This basically searches the available class path for the name element.  Since you are passing an absolute path (and the fact that the code is prefixing it with `/`) means that it can't find the named resource in any of its search locations.  `getResource` is generally used to load resources which are contained within the applications context (ie embedded)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure if understood the code correctcly, but I thought the method "private BufferedImage setzeBilddatei" first checks if the variable "filename" could be found in the application (if stream!=null) and if thats not the case it tries to open the "else if" part.
In CMD it seems as if it already malfunctions at this line "InputStream stream = Bild.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + filename);" as a System.out.println before this line works, but the one after this line won't return.

Comment: @Florian Yes, but it's failing before that point, `/C:/Users/ME/Pictures/fl/stopper-1087835_1280.png` is an invalid path

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I tried to delete the "/"+ but only deleting this part `InputStream stream = Bild.class.getResourceAsStream("" + filename);
   if (stream != null) {
    // lesen aus jar
    System.out.println("Es wird ein Bild aus der JAR gelesen");
    bBild = ImageIO.read(stream);
   } else`of the code worked. I can load my images again,but I still don't know how it came, that it stopped working in the first place... Eventhough thank you for your help, if you got any ideas,what could have gone wrong earlier, please tell me.